# Simultaneously save and print R system call output?

Tags: r

Within my R script I am calling a shell script.  I would like to both print the output to the console in real time and save the output for debugging.  For example:

```
system("script.sh")
```

prints to console in real time,

```
out <- system("script.sh", intern = TRUE)
```

saves the output to a variable for debugging,
and

```
(out <- system("script.sh", intern = TRUE))
```

will only print the contents of `out` after the script has finished. Is there any way to both print to console in real time and store the output as a variable?

Comment: You probably need something like *polling* on a process output. Check out the [`processx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/processx/index.html) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since R is waiting for this to complete anyway, generally to see the stdout *in real time*, you need to poll the process for output. (One can/should also poll for stderr, depending.)

Here's a quick example using [`processx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/processx/index.html).

First, I'll create a slow-output shell script; replace this with the real reason you're calling `system`. I've named this `myscript.sh`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 5` ; do
  sleep 3
  echo 'hello world: '$i
done
```

Now let's (1) start a process in the background, then (2) poll its output every second.

```r
proc <- processx::process$new("bash", c("-c", "./myscript.sh"), stdout = "|")
output <- character(0)
while (proc$is_alive()) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  now <- Sys.time()
  tmstmp <- sprintf("# [%s]", format(now, format = "%T"))
  thisout <- proc$read_output_lines()
  if (length(thisout)) {
    output <- c(output, thisout)
    message(tmstmp, " New output!\n", paste("#>", thisout))
  } else message(tmstmp)
}
# [13:09:29]
# [13:09:30]
# [13:09:31]
# [13:09:32]New output!
#> hello world: 1
# [13:09:33]
# [13:09:34]
# [13:09:35]New output!
#> hello world: 2
# [13:09:36]
# [13:09:37]
# [13:09:38]New output!
#> hello world: 3
# [13:09:39]
# [13:09:40]
# [13:09:41]New output!
#> hello world: 4
# [13:09:42]
# [13:09:43]
# [13:09:44]New output!
#> hello world: 5
```

And its output is stored:

```r
output
# [1] "hello world: 1" "hello world: 2" "hello world: 3" "hello world: 4" "hello world: 5"
```

Ways that this can be extended:

1. Add/store a timestamp with each message, so you know when it came in. The accuracy and utility of this depends on how frequently you want R to poll the process stdout pipe, and really how much you *need* this information.
2. Run the process in the background, and even poll for it in the background cycles. I use the [`later`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/later/index.html) package and set up a self-recurring function that polls, appends, and re-submits itself into the `later` process queue. The benefit of this is that you can continue to use R; the drawback is that if you're running long code, then you will not see output until your current code exits and lets R breathe and do something idly. (To understand this bullet, one really must play with the `later` package, a bit beyond this answer.)
3. Depending on your intentions, it might be more appropriate for the output to go to a file and "permanently" store it there instead of relying on the R process to keep tabs. There are disadvantages to this, in that now you need to manage polling a file for changes, and R isn't making that easy (it does not have, for instance, direct/easy access to `inotify`, so now it gets even more complicated).

Comment: Wonderful! This is super helpful, thanks for the detailed example.  It worked for my purposes.  The script puts out a series of codes that are then parsed into arguments for the next step, but I also want to make sure it doesn't hang.  Your solution has the advantage of saving me a parsing step: `if (length(thisout)) {assign(paste0("arg",i), thisout); i <- i+1}`.

Is there any way of completing this entirely in base commands? I'm not familiar with the processx package and don't want to complicate my dependencies if possible.

Comment: Not easily. `system2` (the lesser of base R's forking evils :-) *does* support backgrounding (forking) the command, and it does support sending its stdout to a file via `stdout=`, but I don't have handy a way to poll the file contents for *just* the newer content (not to mention race conditions with reading a partial line). You can say `stdout=""` and have its standard output to the console ... uncaptured. You can try to `tee` the output to a file and stdout ... in general I find R's `system` (etc) functions a big broken so I welcome `processx`'s better fit. ymmv.